# Why don't I get the name of files and directories?

Tags: php, windows

With the following script, I try to print the list of all the directories and files under those directories. But it doesn't do so.

```
# Snippet that lists all the directories and files under that directory

$dir_list = scandir("/");
for($var=0;$var<count($dir_list);$var++) {
    if(is_dir($dir_list[$var])) {
        $dh = opendir($dir_list[$var]);
        echo "Name of directory : ".$dir_list[$var];
        echo "<br />";
        while(false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
            echo $filename;
            echo "<br />";
        }
    }
    echo $dir_list[$var];echo "<br />";
}
#end
```

Instead, this is what I get as an output. This is the list of all the directories. `if` statement executes only once, when there are so many directories. Why is that ?

```
        $AVG
$RECYCLE.BIN
.Trash-1000
01 - Raanjhanaa - DownloadMing.SE.mp3
05. TUNE YE PHOOL.mp3
16. THUMRI (TRADITIONAL).mp3
AVS Player
Aashiqui 2 {2013} Full Audio Songs Mp3 320kbps
Aye_Khuda_Ret_Ke_Sehar_-_(IndianWap.Mobi).mp3
Baazigar - Chhupana Bhi Nahi Aata (Pankaj Udhas)-(DJmaza.in).mp3
CV [Resume] templates
DWNL_VID
Delhi Belly 2011 Hindi 720p DVDRip x264 Ali Baloch Silver RG.mkv
Name of directory : Devdas - Blu-Ray - 720p - x264 - [DDR]
.
..
Devdas (Sample) - Blu-Ray - 720p - x264 - [DDR].mkv
Devdas (Screenshots) - Blu-Ray - 720p - x264 - [DDR]
Devdas - Blu-Ray - 720p - x264 - [DDR].gif
Devdas - Blu-Ray - 720p - x264 - [DDR].mkv
Devdas - Blu-Ray - 720p - x264 - [DDR].nfo
Devdas - Blu-Ray - 720p - x264 - [DDR]
Dil-Se.avi
Doc
DwnlData
Gangs of Wasseypur II 2012 Hindi 720p DvDRip CharmeLeon Silver RG.mkv
Gayatri-Mantra-Anuradha-Paudwal[www.savevid.com].mp4
Ghalib ghazal - 23.pdf
Ghar_Gulzar_Aapki Aankhon_mein.mp3
Gladiator[Extended.Edition]DvDrip.AC3[Eng]-aXXo
Google Drive
HD-Wallpapers
Hanuman-Chalisa-by-Gulshan-Kumar[www.savevid.com].3gp
I Am Kalam (2010) DVDRip(www.mastitorrents.com).avi
IMG_20120526_191139.jpg
Installed_Apps
Internet Download Manager 6.05 Build 7 Final
Jagjit Singh - Tera Bayaan Ghalib (2012) 128Kbps MP3.rar
Jai-Radha-Hare-Krishna[www.savevid.com].3gp
Java Persistence With Hibernate 2012
Khamoshi 1966
Lakshya.avi
MahaMantra-Hare-Rama-Hare-Krishna-by-Jagjit-Singh[www.savevid.com].3gp
New Folder
New folder (2)
OS images
Om-Gan-Ganapataye-Namo-Namah[www.savevid.com].3gp
Om-Namah-Shivay-(Beautiful-Bhajan-By-Jagjit-Singh)[www.savevid.com].3gp
Pending
PseudoCompiler.cnt
PseudoCompiler.exe
PseudoCompiler.hlp
Ra-One
Ravi Shankar
Rhythm and Blues
ST5UNST.LOG
Shiv Kumar Sharma Torrent
Shiv-Mahamrityunjaya-Mantra[www.savevid.com].3gp
Shree-Hanuman-Chalisa-Anup-Jalota[www.savevid.com].mp4
Special 26 - 2013 DVDRip XviD AC3 M-SuB xRG
System Volume Information
THE-GODFATHER.Part-3.DVDrip[vice]
Taj-Mahal--Secrets-n-Mysteries[www.savevid.com].flv
Tera Bayaan Ghalib Part 1.wmv
Tera Bayaan Ghalib Part 2.wmv
Tera byaan ghalib
The Godfather - II
The Godfather part 1.avi
Untitled Folder
VDI
Vicky Donor - DVDRip - XviD - 1CDRip - [DDR]
VideoLAN - VLC media player for Fedora.htm
VideoLAN - VLC media player for Fedora_files
Visual Fox Pro 9
Visual Fox Pro 9.zip
Windows_Movie_Maker
adding security_niit_glassfish
animated gifs
flipkart
found.000
games_setup
ghazals
htmlProject
httpd-2.2.17
java project
logs
mehdi hassan...arz e niyaaz e isqh ke qabil nahi raha.mp3
music
music_videos
niit
non_music_vidoes
old paper
only jagjit
pagefile.sys
pics
program works
softwares
suhail_1.2
sunny01(www.songs.pk).mp3
tie_1.JPG
tie_2.jpg
```

Comment: You maybe need to pass the full dir path to opendir(), maybe prepending a / would do it

Comment: Which part of this output is not clear on what's going on?

Comment: Assume you are running the script form a web server process? The process may not have mapped E: as you do as an user.

Comment: Does the array contain anything? Try `print_r($dir_list);`

Comment: Scandir does not only return directories, but also files. You may want to use is_dir to check if it's actually a directory.

Comment: @GeenHenk list of all directories

Comment: @Simon returns only directories

Comment: @saplingPro: yes, if there are only directories. Nonetheless, I'd suggest to use is_dir.

Comment: Have you tried ´$dh = opendir("/".$dir_list[$var]);´

Comment: @Simon yes,the same result

Comment: What is the output of print_r($dir_list); ? Please post it.

Comment: @Simon name of all the directories and files which are not directories

Comment: @Simon edited the code in the question

Answer (score 1):

"/" stands for unix based system. Yours seems to be Windows ("E:\").

Try to change `scandir("/")` to `scandir('E:\')`

Comment: what gives `die(__DIR__);` ?

Comment: Also, maybe the user that runs apache (or nginx, or other) doesn't have the read / execution permissions for the dir you are looking for.

Try also your code with `scandir(__DIR__);`

Answer (score 1):

It should be like,

```
$dir_list = scandir("/");

for($var=0;$var<count($dir_list);$var++) {
    if(is_dir($dir_list[$var]))
    {
        $dh = opendir($dir_list[$var]);
        echo "<b>Name of directory : ".$dir_list[$var].'</b><br>';
        if($dh!=false && $dh!= '.' && $dh!='..')
        {
          while(false != ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
              echo $filename;
          }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Name of file : ".$dir_list[$var].'<br>';
    }
}
```

And if you are using windows than in `scandir()` method you should pass the absolute path of the directory.

Comment: I am using windows. I have to get the list of all the files under all the directories. Then I guess there is no concept of absolute path ?

Comment: @saplingPro yes there is. if your current php file is `E:\folder\index.php` then it is absolute path and relative path is always relative to some other file. Such as if in the same folder there is a file `abc.php` and from `index.php` you want to access this file there can be two ways to access 1) relative path - directly i will give `abc.php` and 2) absolute path - i will give here `E:\folder\abc.php`

Comment: I have edited the code in my question. It prints files from only one directory and rest it prints the name of directories. Why it is doing so ?

Comment: because you need to put your code in a function, and call it recursively in case of the current loop check for a directory

Answer (score 0):

As your question is totally different, I made an other answer:

1° you need recursion
2° instead of using complicated function (opendir, readdir) the scandir is enough

Based on your code:

```
<?php

function displayRecursive($path){ 
    $dir_sep = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $path = rtrim($path, '/').'/'; //
$dir_list = scandir($path);
    echo '<ul>';
foreach($dir_list as $file){
        if ($file[0] == '.')
            continue;

        echo '<li>';
        if(is_dir($path.$dir_sep.$file)){
            echo "Name of directory : ".$dir_list[$var];
            displayRecursive($path.$dir_sep.$file);
        }
        else{
            echo $filename;
        }
        echo '</li>';
}
    echo '</ul>';

}
$first_dir = '/';
displayRecursive($first_dir)
```

Comment: can you please explain what is wrong with my code.It prints a directory listings for one and that too for the index number 13 leaving some directories as it flows

Comment: In your code, the `if is_dir` part is missing : you display the name of the file, whatever its type (directory or file) is.

Comment: can we discuss here @http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39751/discussion-between-saplingpro-and-asenar

Comment: I left a query in the chat room